# Javascript add text to an empty div when option is selected from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I have a simple drop down menu that looks like this, with an empty div below:

```
<select class="spb-productdescfont">
   <option value="Text">Text</option>
   <option value="Image">Image</option>
</select>

<div id="custom-type-image">

</div>
```

When the user selects "Image" option, I would like some text to appear in the div below. I am having trouble figuring out the code to do so. This is what I have so far which isn't working:

```
document.querySelector(".spb-productdescfont").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    
if (this[this.selectedIndex].value === "Image") {
      document.querySelector("#custom-type-image").innerHTML = "Hello World!"
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#custom-type-image").innerHTML = ""
    }
});
```

I need to accomplish this using vanilla JS, and without adding an "onchange" event attribute. Can anyone help me? The error I'm getting is "Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null"

Comment: What are the errors you get?

Comment: I cant find anything wrong with your code. It should work.

Comment: I'm getting the error Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.onload in order to reach dom elements

```js
window.onload=function(){
    var activities =  document.querySelector(".productdescfont");
    console.log(activities);
    activities.addEventListener("change", function() {
        document.querySelector("#custom-type-image").innerHTML = activities.value;
    });
}
```

```html
<select class="productdescfont">
   <option value="Text">Text</option>
   <option value="Image">Image</option>
</select>

<div id="custom-type-image">

</div>
```